# Javascript: window.setInterval not invoking function

Tags: coffeescript

I am trying to play an audio file a few times via the Javascript window.setInterval function, and this code for some reason is not working. Is there a better way to do this?

```
MYAPP.utilities = {

  playAudio: (times, interval) ->
    if times == 1
      MYAPP.utilities.playAudioNow()

    if (times > 1) 
      clearIntervalAfterSecs = times * interval 
      playAudioAtIntervals = window.setInterval("MYAPP.utilities.playAudioNow", interval)     
      window.setTimeout(clearInterval(playAudioAtIntervals), clearIntervalAfterSecs)

  playAudioNow: ->
    console.log "Playing Audio now"
    audio_url = $(".play-audio").data("audio")
    myAudio = new Audio(audio_url)    
    myAudio.play()

  playAudioWhenRequested: -> 
      $(".play-audio").click ->
         MYAPP.utilities.playAudio(3, 2000)
}
```

I then call the playAudioWhenRequested when the document is fully loaded. Everything seems to work but the window.setInterval.

```
$(document).ready(MYAPP.utilities.playAudioWhenRequested())
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is riddled with errors, I think you need to learn how to debug. Here are a few questions that might help: (1) What does `clearInterval` return? (2) What does `setTimeout` expect as its first argument? (3) What does `$(document).ready(x)` expect to see in `x` and what you giving it? (4) Why are you using the string form of `setInterval`? (5) Why do you expect `times` to change value in any useful way?

Comment: Thank you @muistooshort. Your questions were spot on, and I fixed and refactored my code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored my code, to use an anonymous function for the setInterval and setTimeout methods that fixed this issue.

```
   (->
      MYAPP.utilities2 =
        playAudio: (times, interval) ->
          audio_url = $(".play-audio").data("audio")
          myAudio = new Audio(audio_url)

          return myAudio.play() if times is 1

          if times > 1
            clearIntervalAfterSecs = times * interval
            playAudioAtIntervals = window.setInterval(->
              myAudio.play()
              return
            , interval)
            to = window.setTimeout(->
              window.clearInterval playAudioAtIntervals
              return
            , clearIntervalAfterSecs)

        playAudioWhenRequested: ->
          $(".play-audio").click ->
            MYAPP.utilities2.playAudio 0, 2000


      return
    ).call this
```